# Custom validation attribute does not show error message

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, validation

tring to compare two date input in asp.net core, i dont get any error message.

other built-in validators are working. also tried to create custom validator too.

(using tuple model. and named it as 'e')

my Model:

```
    public DateTime? SchoolStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SchoolEnd { get; set; }
```

Model Validator (IValidatableObject)

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (SchoolEnd.Value <= SchoolStart.Value)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("End date must be greater than the start date.", new[] { nameof(SchoolEnd) });
            }
        }
```

my view

```
<input asp-for="e.SchoolStart" type="date" class="form-control" data-provider="flatpickr" data-date-format="d F Y" placeholder="Başlangıç Tarihi" />

<input asp-for="e.SchoolEnd" type="date" class="form-control" data-provider="flatpickr" data-date-format="d F Y" placeholder="Bitiş Tarihi" />
```

Comment: I don't see where you're actually calling the validator here. What is triggering validation?

Comment: @ClearlyClueless im using jquery  validation and jquery unobtrusive. I forget to add there is also a span under inputs for asp-validation-for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is backend validation, The error message will show after `ModelState.IsValid`, Please refer to this simple demo:

**Model**

```
public class DataModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Test { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SchoolStart { get; set; }

        [CustomAdmissionDate]
        public DateTime? SchoolEnd { get; set; }
    }
```

**validate class**

```
public class CustomAdmissionDate : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var model = (DataModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance;


            if (model.SchoolEnd <= model.SchoolStart)
            {
                return new ValidationResult("End date must be greater than the start date.");
                
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

**Backend post method**

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult validate(DataModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             return View(model);
        }
             return View();
   }
```

**View**

```
@model DataModel

 <form asp-action="Validate">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Test" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Test" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Test" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SchoolStart" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="SchoolStart" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="SchoolStart" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SchoolEnd" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="SchoolEnd" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="SchoolEnd" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}
```

**Demo:**

[image]

=========Update=========

If you wanna achieve client validation, you need to create a client script, Please update `CustomAdmissionDate` class to:

```
public class CustomAdmissionDate : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
    {
        public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
        {

            context.Attributes.Add("data-val", "true");
            context.Attributes.Add("data-val-date", "End date must be greater than the start date.");
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            //........
        }
    }
```

Then create js file named `Date.js` in `wwwroot/js/Date.js`

**Date.js**

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("date",
    function (value, element, param) {
        var starttime = document.getElementById("SchoolStart").value;
        var start = Date.parse(starttime);
        var end = Date.parse(value)
        if (end <= start) { 
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Then refer this js file in your page:

`<script src="~/js/Date.js"></script>`

Now it can be validated in client site.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I’m able to use error messages on client when use build in validators ( like required ) I’m using jquery unobtrusive for show error messages I forget to add there is also a span under inputs for asp-validation-for

Comment: Hi, So you wanna validate it in client side right?

Comment: yes I want to validate in client @xinran-shen

Comment: Hi @Selcukusu, Please check my update in answer, I provide a simple demo about how to achieve it via client validation

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I’m able to use client validations without writing client side validator. It’s necessary for custom validations?

Comment: In this case, How do you use client validation without custom validator?

Comment: i only write validation in model. i dont write any function in client side.

Comment: From MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#client-side-validation), I think in your case you need to custom client validation.